# Unexpected output at the end of PHP Script using Google Cloud

Tags: php, ajax

When I call my PHP script via ajax, it returns the output correctly but adds a string like this at the end of the output.

```
<!-- 0.072843074798584 seg. -->
```

Can anyone please tell me why this is happening and how to fix it?

PHP version 5.6.29

`PS : The number mentioned in the output is different everytime.`

Comment: It looks like an execution time or some other measurement.

Comment: I am guessing that it has something to do with Segmentation Fault, that is why its mentioned seg.
Because there is no other echo command or other ways of printing this kind of output at the end of my script.

Comment: Segmentation Fault? No way.

Comment: What could it be then?